# Code with bool not working expected C#

Tags: c#, boolean

I've been working on a draft login centre ( Yes, I know, I will transfer the storing of passwords and usernames to a database or hash it later ) and I ran into a problem with my bool code to see whether the username existed. The bool code that checks login user is always false.
EDIT: Small code snippet:

```
bool userContain = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\Passwords.txt").Contains(loginUser);
                Console.WriteLine(userContain);
                if (loginUser == "")
                { Console.WriteLine("Error.... Username is empty.. stop trying to glitch the system ;("); }
                else
                {
                    if (userContain == true)
                    {
                        if (lineCount == countLine) { Console.WriteLine("Logged In!"); loginAttempt = 1; } else { Console.WriteLine("Error:Password or User incorrect!"); }
                    }

                    else { Console.WriteLine("Error, Username does not exist"); }
                }
```

Edit: Stupid typo.... thanks for pointing it out. I'm mentally bashing myself multiple times now.....

Comment: What error you get exactly? What is your problem? It is not clear what your problem is IMO..

Comment: Oh sorry if I didn't make it clear, it wasn't an error. Whoops, going to edit the question now. The bool code that checks login user is always false.

Comment: Too much code! Find a smaller example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: BTW, instead of `if (userContain == true)` - simply write `if (userContain)`

Comment: @ops Ok. Didn't change anything :P Thanks anyway for reminding me to shorten it.

Comment: Yes, mechron is in the file for usernames. No caps, thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version checks if there's a line equal to the username, when it's probably just a part of the line.

```
bool userContain = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\Passwords.txt").Any(s=>IsInLine(s,userLogin));
```

Implement `IsInLine` so it matches your data representations - for example, if each line in the passwords file is of format "mechron,123", `IsInLine` can use string.Split(',') and compare against the first token.

Also, maybe it's a case issue. If usernames are case-insensitive, then it's best to normalize the case (using `ToLower()`, for example) before comparing.

Comment: Didn't work :/ What does the .Any(s=>s.Contains(loginUser)); do?

Comment: It performs the predicate on every line and returns true iff one of the lines return true. In our case - it checks whether there's a line that contain the user name.

Comment: So when using your code, if user opd is in the file, then so are users o, op and pd. Might be his problem, but this is not the solution.

Comment: Weston - you're right. Mechron - can you give us an example line from the passwords file?